# HTTPS redirect with Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having trouble with https redirection on my website build with React and Express.
Basically, although I've got redirection set up exactly as on other website (that has server side rendering) where everything works fine. Here I cannot get it to work.

Express code snippet:

```
const express = require('express')
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const helmet = require('helmet')
require('dotenv').config()
app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

app.enable("trust proxy")

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   if (req.secure) {
       next();
   } else {
       res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
   }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Main react:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Main from './components/Main'
import FloatingButton from './components/FloatingButton'
import Work from './components/Work'



function App() {


  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/" component={FloatingButton} />
      <Route path="/works/:workName" component={Work}/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why it doesn't redirect?

Comment: I'm assuming you're speaking of your express redirect where you're looking to see if your user is using an https connection and redirecting if they're not? If so, then in order to confirm your configuration, we'd need to see what port express is listening to and see at least a screenshot of your attempt showing that it's not redirecting. My assumption is that you're listening on port 443 and you're expecting port 80 traffic to be redirected to port 443 (secure) automatically. Since express isn't listening on port 80, it can't.

Comment: @technicallynick in the express code it's listening on port(3000) but that doesn't matter really (I think) because the hosting I'm using uses phusion passenger where ports are automatically assigned. 

I edited the code above so full server js is visible. also webiste address is http://cravetheweb.com

Answer (score 0):

When using something like Phusion Passenger, your express port is only bound internally. It's not what the outside user is utilizing. So when you set your environment to listen to port 3000, Phusion is set to forward traffic from 80 and/or 443 to your port 3000, but internally it's likely all secured, regardless of the outside experience. To do https redirects in Phusion Passenger, please see their documentation that I've liked below:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html

Specifically, they've got a configuration section with this information:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helps to understand the server side better! However I actually found the solution, because it was weird to me that the same piece of middleware worked on my different website (that is not React) and didn't here. Basically, the middleware has to be called before express uses static files from react build

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution myself. 
It turns out that middleware that is responsible for redirection has to be called before static files are served. Otherwise, that code is never executed. 
Below the correct server code flow

```
const express = require('express')
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require('path')
const app = express()


const helmet = require('helmet')
require('dotenv').config()


app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.enable("trust proxy")

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  if (req.secure) {
      next();
  } else {
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense (logically) to me, but I'm glad you found something that works!